# Go can't find file while running as a systemctl service on Ubuntu

Tags: go, systemctl

I have a Go app, and I'm trying to run it as a `systemctl` service (Ubuntu 18.04).

I'm using [godotenv](https://github.com/joho/godotenv):

```
func init() {
    var env map[string]string
    env, err := godotenv.Read()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

I have my `.env` file in the same directory where my executable is.

I've created a `service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=my go app
Requires=local-fs.target
After=rsyslog.service

[Service]
Type=forking
GuessMainPID=no
StandardInput=null
ExecStart=/var/path/to/my/app/main

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

After executing `sudo systemctl start my-go-app.service`, then `sudo systemctl status my-go-app.service`, I got these in my logs:

> Starting my-go-app...
>   panic: open .env: no such file or directory

What's wrong?

While executing `main` directly, there are no such problems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I have my .env file in the same directory where my executable is.

Then you need to configure your working directory to match:

```
[Service]
...
WorkingDirectory=/var/path/to/my/app
```

Remember to run `systemctl daemon-reload` after changing any unit file.

Comment: Please, add `systemctl daemon-reload` after changing `.service` file, so I can accept your answer

Comment: You may also need to restart the app: `systemctl restart <appname>`